# i7 dell latitude 5290 2-in-1 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, dell, tablet

So I have come into possession of subject "convertible" PC with the only condition being I have to pull the SSD and destroy it.  I have a 50 ton press LOL.

So I would like to dual boot this machine between Ubuntu and W10.  I have Ubuntu experience but never tried dual boot.

Is there a guide somewhere?  Which OS do I start with? (I know I gotta buy W10). I plan to get either 0.5T or 1T SSD.  Suggestions or cautions?

Comment: Following this! I'd be very interested too.